# Creating a Stack<T> with anonymous type

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types

I have the a class Foo like this:

```
 class Foo
 {
  public int id{get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Foo> Childs;
       //some other properties
 }
```

Now I want to process some business logic on a Foo-Object and all it's children like this:

```
 public void DoSomeWorkWith(Foo x)
 {
  var firstItem = new {level = 0, item = x};
  var s = new Stack<?>(?); //What type to use?
  s.Push(firstItem);
  while(s.Any())
  {
    var current = s.Pop();
    DoSomeBusiness(current.item);
    DoSomeMoreBusiness(current.item);
    Log(current.level, current.item.id);
    foreach(Foo child in current.item.Childs)
       s.Push(new {level = current.level + 1, item = child});
   }
}
```

I need to keep track of the (relative) level/depth of the childs. 
How do I create a `Stack<T>` for the anonymous type? Of course I could create a simple class instead of the anonymous type (or a more complicated recursive function), but how to solve this problem without an additional class?

Comment: Can you please format your code :)

Comment: `Childs` reads a bit strangely, given that the English plural of 'child' is 'children' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just put it into a method like this:

```
public Stack<T> CreateStackWithInitialItem<T>(T initialItem)
{
    var s = new Stack<T>();
    s.Push(initialItem);
    return s;
}
```

and then use it like that:

```
public void DoSomeWorkWith(Foo x)
{
    var s = CreateStackWithInitialItem(new {level = 0, item = x});
    while(s.Any())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
public static Stack<T> CreateEmptyStack<T>(T template) {
    return new Stack<T>();
}
...
var stack = CreateEmptyStack(firstItem);
```

This uses generic type inference to handle the `T`.

Answer (score 1):

What about using tuples (`System.Tuple<>`) instead of anonymous types?

```
public void DoSomeWorkWith(Foo x)
{
    var firstItem = new Tuple<int, Foo>(0, x);
    var s = new Stack<Tuple<int, Foo>>();
    s.Push(firstItem);
    while (s.Any())
    {
        var current = s.Pop();
        DoSomeBusiness(current.Item2);
        DoSomeMoreBusiness(current.Item2);
        Log(current.Item1, current.Item2.id);
        foreach (Foo child in current.Item2.Childs)
            s.Push(new Tuple<int, Foo>(current.Item1 + 1, child));
    }
}
```

Even though this is not the primary use case for dynamic objects (through you know all types involved at design time) you could also make use of `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`.
If you do so, be sure to test for performance differences because of the overhead.

```
public void DoSomeWorkWith(Foo x)
{
    dynamic firstItem = new ExpandoObject();
    firstItem.level = 1;
    firstItem.item = x;

    var s = new Stack<dynamic>();
    s.Push(firstItem);
    while (s.Any())
    {
        var current = s.Pop();
        DoSomeBusiness(current.item);
        DoSomeMoreBusiness(current.item);
        Log(current.level, current.item.id);
        foreach (Foo child in current.item.Childs)
        {
            dynamic next = new ExpandoObject();
            next.level = current.level + 1;
            next.item = child;
            s.Push(next);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code by using recursion instead of pushing things onto a temporary stack and temporary objects.  For example:

```
// (If you're not using C# 4, you can replace the default level with a function
// overload or just remove the default value)

void ProcessFooRecursive(Foo foo, int level = 0) 
{
    DoSomeBusiness(foo);
    DoSomeMoreBusiness(foo);
    Log(level, foo.id);

    var newDepth = level + 1;
    foreach (var child in foo.Childs)
    {
        ProcessFooRecursive(child, newDepth);
    }
}
```